# Compute Engine does not connect to Cloud SQL, but works from local workstation and App Engine

Tags: php, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL database at Cloud SQL.  I use it with App Engine and PHP just fine.  I can connect to it from a local Apache server and PHP just fine.

When trying the same script on my Compute Engine instance is does not work: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

- I have entered the Compute Engine IP in the Cloud SQL allowed connections setting.
- I have made the SQL user "xxx@%"
- Compute Engine is Debian 9
- SELinux is not running

Here is my connection code:

```
    // MySQL Settings:
    $dbuser='xxx';
    $dbpassword='yyy';
    $dbname='zzz';
    $dbconnection = "aaaa:us-central1:aaaa-sql";
    $_SESSION['db_source'] = 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/'.$dbconnection.';dbname='.$dbname;

try {
    $db = new PDO($_SESSION['db_source'], $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include('errors/db_error.php');
    exit;
}
```

Why would this work on App Engine and Locally, but not on Compute Engine? Is there something that needs to be installed or running?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$dbconnection = "aaaa:us-central1:aaaa-sql";
$_SESSION['db_source'] = 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/'.$dbconnection.';dbname='.$dbname;
```

There are two ways to connect from software running on Compute Engine to Cloud SQL.

The first method is to specify the [Cloud SQL IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) in your connection string. That also means that you must configure the Compute Engine IP address as an [authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks).

```
$cloud_sql_ip_addr = 'REPLACE_ME';
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $dbname . ';host=' . $cloud_sql_ip_addr;
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

The second method is to install and configure the [Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).

```
$cloud_sql_ip_addr = '127.0.0.1';
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $dbname . ';host=' . $cloud_sql_ip_addr;
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

Comment: Trying the second method ...  but getting error when running cloud_sql_proxy

./cloud-sql-proxy xxxx:us-central1:xxxx-sql

googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings",
      "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
  }
]

More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which service account to edit, and I don't seem to be allowed to edit any of them.

Comment: @Mark - You have multiple problems. My answer solves your first one. Create a new post with details on the next problem. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input!